# Работа с TFile.ReadAllLines

Tags: delphi

Предоставлен, полностью, рабочий код:

**У меня возник вопрос:**

Как правильно переделать код что бы место **TFile.ReadAllLines('all.txt');** - был **OpenDialog1.FileName**

И сохранения шло через  **writeln();**

**Рабочий код:**

```
   uses System.IOUtils, System.Types;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  A: TStringDynArray;
  Index: array of integer;
  Unic, Rez: TStringList;
  i, j, k: integer;
  s: String;

begin
  A := TFile.ReadAllLines('all.txt');
  SetLength(Index, Length(A));
  Unic := TStringList.Create;
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do
  begin
    s := Copy(A[i], Pos('№', A[i]) + 1, Pos('>', A[i]) - Pos('№', A[i]) - 1);
    k := Unic.IndexOf(s);
    if k = -1 then
      Index[i] := Unic.Add(s)
    else
      Index[i] := k;
  end;
  for i := 0 to Unic.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Rez := TStringList.Create;
    for j := Low(Index) to High(Index) do
      if Index[j] = i then
        Rez.Add(A[j]);
    Rez.SaveToFile(Format('%s%s.txt', [ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)),
      Unic.Strings[i]]));
    Rez.Free;
  end;
  Unic.Free;
end;
```

**Мои усилия, ошибки после которых ничего не вышло (Строго не судите поскольку я очень не опытный в программировании но стремлюсь и учу):**

```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f, f1: TextFile;
  Index: array of integer;
  Unic, Rez: TStringList;
  i, j, k: integer;
  s: String;
  mas: array of string;
begin
  // Открываем диалог выбора файла
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(f, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    reset(f);
    AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + Format('%s%s.txt',
      [ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), Unic.Strings[i]]));
    rewrite(f1);
  end;

  SetLength(Index, Length(s));
  Unic := TStringList.Create;
  for i := Low(mas) to High(mas) do
  begin
    s := Copy(s, Pos('№', s) + 1, Pos('>', s) - Pos('№', s) - 1);
    k := Unic.IndexOf(s);
    if k = -1 then
      Index[i] := Unic.Add(s)
    else
      Index[i] := k;
  end;

  // Проходим по строкам в файле
  while not Eof(f) do
  begin
    ReadLn(f, s);

    for i := 0 to Unic.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Rez := TStringList.Create;
      for j := Low(Index) to High(Index) do
        if Index[j] = i then
          Rez.Add(s[j]);
      writeln(f1, Rez.Text);
    end;
    Unic.Free;

  end;

  CloseFile(f);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Comment: А зачем портить "полностью рабочий код" ?

Comment: Так вроде у Вас всё есть - вот построчное чтение во втором куске `while not Eof(f) do  begin  ReadLn(f, s);` , используйте его в первом и работайте со строкой `s` вместо `A[i]` в первом куске.

Comment: К сожалению, Вы вообще не думаете, что делаете. Ну примитивная же логика - прочитали одну строку, обработали. Где чтение из файла в строку s? На кой там вообще массив и цикл for? Из чего устанавливается первый SetLength?

Comment: Посмотрите, как сделано после строк `// Проходим по строкам в файле`

Comment: @MBo, Я так понял нужно убрать цикл  for i := 0 to Unic.Count - 1 do и цикл for j := Low(Index) to High(Index) do Правильно ?

Comment: @MBo, Ладно, решить задачу я не могу. Пройдет пару дней и выставлю вознаграждения за решение вопроса.